# Calculated field from variable value

Tags: powershell

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this PowerShell `SELECT` statement? I am trying to add a calculated property and assign a value from a variable. As seen in the debugger screencapture below, there the property values are displayed. But when added to the property the values are blank.

```
foreach ($ws in $Groups) {
    # Variables
    $wsName = $ws.Name.ToString()
    $wsId = $ws.Id.ToString()
    $Fileout = "C:\OneDrive\BI\OneDrive - Circle 9\PBI\Reports\$wsName\_EXPORT"
    # Workspaces
    $wsReports = Get-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $ws.Id
    $wsReports | SELECT *, @{Name = 'Workspace'; Expression = $wsName} , @{Name = 'WorkspaceId'; Expression = $wsId} 

    Write-Host($ws.Name + "...")
    Write-Host(($wsReports.count).ToString() + " report count") -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor DarkGreen

    $wsReportsAll += $wsReports
 #   $wsReports | ft -auto
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot the curly braces for the expressions ... `@{Name = 'Workspace'; Expression = {$wsName} } , @{Name = 'WorkspaceId'; Expression = {$wsId} } `

Comment: @Olaf - Yours is the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you want the *value* of a variable to be used for a calculated property, then you have to enclose it in curly braces:

```
$wsReports | SELECT *, @{Name = 'Workspace'; Expression = { $wsName }} , @{Name = 'WorkspaceId'; Expression = { $wsId }}
```

This assigns actual script blocks as the expressions. The script blocks return the value of the variables, by using PowerShells implicit output behaviour.

The syntax you were using (that is, assigning a string to `Expression`) has a different meaning. It would look for a property named like the value of the variable in `$wsReports`. E. g. `Expression = $wsName` would work like `Select -Property 'Accounting BI Reports'`. This *can* be useful for renaming properties, but is not what you actually want.